# How to adjust the position of a mesh model before drawing

Tags: c#, windows, model, xna, fbx

I started programming in XNA. I developed a project simple will load a "fbx"mesh model  exported from blender. Everything works perfectly.
But now I want to duplicate / copied my model several times to create a floor! a matrix of 10 X 10 model.
I tried several code does not work. Here is my sample code.

I do not understand why I can not duplicate my model.

Thank you very much.

```
//Function draw models mesh
    private void draw_groundLand1()
    {
        //Draw 10 times model texture to make small ground
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
        {     
            // Copy any parent transforms.
            Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model_ground_land1.Bones.Count];
            model_ground_land1.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

            // Draw the model. A model can have multiple meshes, so loop.
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model_ground_land1.Meshes)
            {
                // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
                // as our camera and projection.
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {

                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                Matrix.CreateRotationY(cubeGroundLand1_modelRotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(cubeGroundLand1_position);
                    effect.View = View;
                    //effect.Texture = text_ground_lan1;
                    effect.Projection = Projection;
                }
                // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
                mesh.Draw();
            }

            //Move position for the next mesh modal to draw
            cubeGroundLand1_position.X += (float)1.0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found my solution -> juste move this code ligne "cubeGroundLand1_position.X += (float)1.0;"

like:

```
private void draw_groundLand1()
    {

        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
        {
            // Copy any parent transforms.
            Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model_ground_land1.Bones.Count];
            model_ground_land1.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

            // Draw the model. A model can have multiple meshes, so loop.
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model_ground_land1.Meshes)
            {

                // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
                // as our camera and projection.
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {

                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                Matrix.CreateRotationY(cubeGroundLand1_modelRotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(cubeGroundLand1_position);
                    effect.View = View;
                    //effect.Texture = text_ground_lan1;
                    effect.Projection = Projection;

                    cubeGroundLand1_position.X = (float)a+1;
                }
                // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
```